# Automatic asset replacement at a fixed time

Tags: publishing, media-library, rules-engine, versions

We want to schedule an automatic asset (graphic, text etc) replacement. Here is my plan that makes the purpose also clear.

I want a particular image to get automatically replaced at midnight on certain days (say Dec 25, Jan 1).

I plan to create 3 versions of the images (1=current, 2=Christmas, 3=New Year). I will set the publish and unpublish dates for each version.

How do I setup things so that the version 2 of the image goes live at midnight on Dec 25 and replaces the version 1 of the image. Similarly, on Jan 1st, the version 3 should go live and replace version 2.

**Concerns:**
1. We need to arrange for self-publishing of the assets at that time.

2. Do we need to republish the pages using this image also? (There are about 100).

**Notes:**

1. I do not care about the exact time for the publish. So a few seconds early or late won't matter much.

Can you please advise a solution or point me to some resource? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about personalization rules? If date > 25.12 use another datasource?

Comment: Thanks. I will try that route. However, can we not use a scheduled publishing job to publish and unpublish at those times?

Comment: If you have already some autopublishing engine in your solution and if you really really want to use it, then yes. Go ahead. If not, you can use personalization without writing a single line of code (assuming that your images are datasource driven)

Comment: Thanks Marek. Can you please elaborate: "...images are datasource driven"?

Comment: The solution we are having decent success so far (the testing is continuing): 
Activate the AutoPublish setting, set a decent time interval (we used 1 hour as of now).

Comment: The solution we have employed so far (the testing is continuing): 

Activate the AutoPublish setting, set a decent time interval (we used 1 hour as of now).

Put a new version of the offer image and make it unpublishable at a certain date and time. We are proceeding in reverse order. The current one is the highest, next one is the lower one.

Now at the set time, the latest version (current offer) becomes unpublishable. Autopublish daemon publishes the lower version and that changes the offer.

Do you see any issues with this arrangement?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a correct solution for you to use **Publishing Restrictions**.

Sitecore [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/set_up_publishing_restrictions_for_an_item):

> If you specify a date range for when an item or item version is
>   publishable, it does not mean that the item is published on the start
>   date and removed again on the end date. Instead, it means that the
>   item is available for publishing and included when you publish that
>   item or the entire website. To make an item appear on your website on
>   the start date and removed again on the end date, you must run the
>   Publish Item wizard on both days.

As *Marek Musielak* suggested, will be better if you will use personalization rules where you can set conditions for change datasource, which will depend on specific dates

Answer (score 0):

Just set the proper Publishing Restrictions for all three versions and let the Sitecore publishes all three versions. Publishing server should be able to manage this as described for example here: [Sitecore Publishing Server and Content Availability](http://thegrumpycoder.com/tagged/publishing-server)